# How do I pass a var text into a PHP var

Tags: javascript, php, variables

In this script how do I send the RESULT of the wheel to a PHP variable?

```
function stopRotateWheel() {
clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
ctx.save();
ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
var text = restaraunts[index]
ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
ctx.restore();
```

}

More specific "VAR TEXT = RESTARAUNTS[index]"

Can this be sent to a $turnresult PHP variable?

Comment: It can, with **ajax** !

Comment: you don't "send to a php variable". You send a query parameter/submit a form to a PHP script, which can then populate the variable with whatever you're passing along.

Comment: To elaborate on what Marc B said, you would be sending a request via Ajax to another PHP script (or another instance of this one) not to this same instance because PHP runs first, then transmits the page to the client, then JS runs. So if you're trying to share a variable between this PHP page and JS, having the JS run first, that's not possible because the PHP always runs first.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do that. Lets say you have:

```
function stopRotateWheel() {
clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
ctx.save();
ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
var text = restaraunts[index]
ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
ctx.restore();

//this is an easy solution to pass in value of text to php
window.location.href = "myvar.php?text=" + text; 

}
```

or you can do it with JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var text = '<?php echo $text ?>';
</script>
```

To send a Javascript value to PHP you'd need to use AJAX. With jQuery, it would be like this:

```
var text = 'data';
$.post('myvar.php', {variable: text});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use some ajax. If you have access to jQuery,

```
var result = "<?php echo $someValue; ?>";  // or whatever else you'd like
$.ajax({
    url: 'myscript.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "result=" + result,
    success: function(success) {
        alert(success);
    }
});
```

Take a look here: [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)